# Not seeing my heroku celery workers stats on new-relic

Tags: python, heroku, celery, newrelic

I have a python server running on heroku with one web dyno and an additional dyno running my celery tasks.

I added the new-relic add-on and can see monitoring data for my application except data for my celery tasks. When checking under the "Background tasks" tab I see a message saying `New Relic recorded no Celery background task executions in the last 7 days` (I am certain my celery tasks are working correctly).

In addition I get the following error on my heroku logs (Although it is reported by both dynos so I am not sure it's related)

> Data collector is not contactable. This can be because of a network
>   issue or because of the data collector being restarted. In the event
>   that contact cannot be made after a  period of time then please report
>   this problem to New Relic support for further  investigation. The
>   error raised was ConnectionError(MaxRetryError('Max retries exceeded 
>   for url:
>   /agent_listener/invoke_raw_method?run_id=XXX&method=metric_data&license_key=XXX&protocol_version=12&marshal_format=json',),).

I should mention I am currently on the *free* tier of new-relic however I couldn't find anything saying this is only for the *paid* version.

Comment: If you haven't already, you would better off contacting New Relic support. If using the Heroku add on for New Relic, better to go through Heroku support and they will pass it across.

Comment: I've hit similar problem (no on Heroku however), it was temporary and probaby due to newrelic datacollector was indeed restarting.